# Reverse Message Program

Tags: python, strings

```
# Alex Grattan
# 17/10/14

message = input("Enter your message to have it printed backwards:")
split_message = list(message.split())
reverse_message_list = []
reverse_message = ""

for i in range(len(split_message)):
    reverse_message_list.append(split_message.pop())

reverse_message_list = [x + ' ' for x in reverse_message_list]

for i in reverse_message_list:
    reverse_message += i

print (reverse_message)
```

Answer (score 6):

- `split` returns a list already, so you don't need the `list` call
- unless you really want to reimplement the `reverse` method, use it, or the function `reversed` if you want a return value instead
- concatenating strings is much easier with `" ".join(...)`

So this can then be compressed to

```
# Alex Grattan
# 17/10/14

message = input("Enter your message to have it printed backwards:")
print (" ".join(reversed(message.split())))
```

Comment: Thanks! No I don't have a specific question. I am an autodidact, so I seek guidance and code reviews from others.

Comment: I wasn't aware the 'reverse' method existed - the novice I am. Google is my friend; I should have consulted her.

Comment: Cool, I removed the question; also [the standard library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) are pretty good if you're looking for something related to e.g. standard types.

Answer (score 3):

Why even go the route of `for` loops and calling `join` and `reversed` when you can just use [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)?

```
message = input("Enter your message to have it printed backwards:")
print message[::-1]
```

the output would then be:

```
> Enter your message to have it printed backwards: 
    My name is Inigo Montoya, you have killed my father, prepare to die

eid ot eraperp ,rehtaf ym dellik evah uoy ,ayotnoM oginI si eman yM
```

**EDIT**: Per @ferada's comment, this reverses the sentence by words, not letters:

```
message = raw_input("Enter your message to have it printed backwards:")
print " ".join(message.split()[::-1])
```

and the output:

```
> Enter your message to have it printed backwards: 
    My name is Inigo Montoya, you have killed my father, prepare to die

die to prepare father, my killed have you Montoya, Inigo is name My
```

Also, do be mindful of the [`input()`/`raw_input()` cross-compat issue with Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: Because the result is different? Splitting first will then just reverse the order of words, whereas this reverses the whole string.

Comment: @ferada updated my answer to reflect reversing words using the extended slices. Similar to your answer, minus the call to `reversed()`.